# How to Position Admob Banner for iOS on Top Centre?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I am using this code to position the Admob banner on top left. How to change the position to top centre?

```
bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner]
    autorelease];
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"my-id";
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Comment: bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];

Answer (score 1):

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 50)];
    // Need to set this to no since we're creating this custom view.
    abmob.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
    // before compiling.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = AdMob_ID;
    bannerView_.delegate = self;
    [bannerView_ setRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
```

May be it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not position the banner in centre.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a banner ad like this :

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] init];
```

Give it frame size like this:

```
bannerView_.frame =  frameSize;
```

For frame size, you can make a UIView in your nib at whatever place you like and give its frameSize, i.e its `bounds` to `bannerView_.frame` or you can also directly give frame size to banner ad directly:

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not position the banner in centre.

Comment: You can create the view where ever you want, even in the center or you can also change center of bannerview like this : bannerView_.center = CGPointMake(ScreenSize.width/2,centerY);

Comment: The problem is the width of screen size for devices varies. For iPhone 6 is 375 and iPhone 6 plus is 414. Sow what should I set for ScreenSize.width/2?

Comment: CGsize screenSize      = [[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] size]; CGFloat widthOfScreen  = screenSize.width;